# International connection at Seattle-Tacoma airport

Tags: customs-and-immigration, transit, international-travel, pre-clearance

I am flying from Vancouver to Seattle, then Seattle to Tokyo-Narita, with Delta connection in single ticket.
I would like to confirm if my understandings for this connection are correct or not.

1. Vancouver airport (YVR) has US CBP, which means I finish US immigration and customs process at Vancouver and I don't need to redo them at Seattle.
2. Once I check in my luggage at Vancouver, this luggage goes all the way to Tokyo-Narita and I don't need to pick the luggage up at Seattle.

I am especially interested about luggage connection, since I only have limited time (57min layover) in Seattle.

Answer (score 10):

Your understanding is 100% correct (can't write anything more than that)

If going back the same way, however, you'll clear US immigration in Seattle, then collect and re-check your luggage at the designated counter after customs.

Comment: You might mention that it will work a little differently on the return journey.